# How to create a project using tns create without using any templates

Tags: nativescript

Hello I wanted to create a nativescript project from terminal without using any templates, I wanted to just start from scratch. But, tns create won't allowed me to do that, it shows lists of templates. Is there any command that let me just create nativescript project from scratch? Thanks

Comment: You may use the simple Hello World template, that is from scratch has nothing more than a Label and Button.

Comment: But I didn't want that, I just wanna have my own project structure and create nativescript in that folder.

Comment: So then you are good to just created a folder and initiate the `package.json` file using NPM (assuming it's a Core NS project). TNS will just look for the app folder inside and the other `package.json` inside app folder for the main file.

Comment: ok thanks, though I'm expecting this from tns I will do that ma self. I didn't get why nativescript won't give such choices in terminal [tns create].

Comment: You can try the `blank` template (`tns create newApp --template=tns-template-blank`). It's an empty NativeScript app from scratch.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was looking for.